# ActiveRecord: Has many through (twice)

Tags: ruby, activerecord

There are `Thing`s in `Place`s which I'm looking to find. One `Thing` could be in many different `Place`s, and many `Thing`s can be in one `Place`.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :places
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :things
end
```

I want to record the `Find`s of my `User`s so that I know where they found what.

```
class Find < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :places_thing # Is this depluralization correct?
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :finds
  # Now, how can I link in the Things the user has found? Like this?
  has_many :found_things_in_places, :class_name => :places_things, :through => :finds
  has_many :things, :through => :thought_things_in_places
end
```

Does this seem right? is it efficient? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you were on the right track, the big change I'd make is that rather than having a join table (places_things) you should make it a proper model. I decided to call this an existence.

The data only exists in one place, so it's properly normalized. These relationships are clear and will be easy to manage. I think it's efficient.

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :existences
  has_many :things, :through => :existences
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :existences
  has_many :places, :through => :existences
end

class Existence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :thing
end

class Find < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :existence
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :finds
  has_many :existences, :through => :finds
  has_many :things, :through => :existences
end
```

You'll need rails 3.1 to do the nested has many through's like we did in User.

BTW the correct association declaration should be: belongs_to :places_things

Comment: When you say you need Rails 3.1, do you mean ActiveRecord 3.1? I'm using ActiveRecord 3.0.9, which I think is the latest gem, outside of Rails (with Sinatra in fact) and I'm getting errors when I try `user.things`.

Comment: Well, I don't think you'd ever want to use rails 3.0.x with AR 3.1. I'm sure you'd uncover some interesting bugs. Rails 3.1 is at RC6 now, so if you want to use rails 3.1, you'd need to include gem "rails", '~> 3.1.rc' in your Gemfile.

Comment: I'm actually not using Rails at all, I'm using AR with Sinatra. Do you know what I'd need to require in order to get the nested :has_many :throughs?

Comment: try: gem install activerecord --pre then require 'activerecord'.